# ListView with images only

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, listview

I was just asking myself if there was a way of making a ListView without any texts. I've only found ListViews with images + texts, and that exactly what i dont want. I just want to add a lot of images like in a list and don't want to make it with ImageView because that makes my app crash. Also, i dont want my app to lag. Thanks!

this is what i got in my activity_main.xml

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

/>

and i found this from another post that actually helped me, but it doesnt display all images

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


// Array of integers points to images stored in /res/drawable-hdpi/
int[] vehs = new int[]{
    R.drawable.veh1,
    R.drawable.veh2,
    R.drawable.veh3,
    R.drawable.veh4,
    R.drawable.veh5,
    R.drawable.veh6,
    R.drawable.veh7,
    R.drawable.veh8,
    R.drawable.veh9,
    R.drawable.veh10,
    R.drawable.veh11,
    R.drawable.veh12,
    R.drawable.veh13,
    R.drawable.veh14,
    R.drawable.veh15,
    R.drawable.veh16,
    R.drawable.veh17,
    R.drawable.veh18,
    R.drawable.veh19,
    R.drawable.veh20,
    R.drawable.veh21,
    R.drawable.veh22,
    R.drawable.veh23,
    R.drawable.veh24,
    R.drawable.veh25,
    R.drawable.veh26,
    R.drawable.veh27,
    R.drawable.veh28,
    R.drawable.veh29,
    R.drawable.veh30,
    R.drawable.veh31,
    R.drawable.veh32,
    R.drawable.veh33,
    R.drawable.veh34,
    R.drawable.veh35,
    R.drawable.veh36,
};


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("vehs", Integer.toString(vehs[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "vehs","txt","cur" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.vehs,R.id.txt,R.id.cur};

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Didn't edit all the code, so you might find some things confusing xD

Comment: could you post your code ?

Comment: some code will help me to understand your point :)

Comment: @mohammedmomn I actually dont have a code, was hoping you could show me a basic one where i can just add the images.

Comment: @mohammedmomn but sure, i can try

Comment: You shouldn't use android:layout_height="wrap_content" in a ListView.
It will cause a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

The way `ListView` displays data is by using an **adapter**. The adapter takes your data, inserts it into a custom view, and then adds it to the list.

To build a fast images `ListView`, the first thing you'd want to do is to add [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to your project. This library will automatically download and cache your images, handle `ImageView` recycling, and more.

The next thing you'd want to do is to write your item view. If you want an images-only list, the view could be as simple as:

```
<!-- res/layout/list_item.xml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" />
```

Next, you want to create your adapter. It accepts a `List<String>` of image URLs as an input, builds the items and inserts them to the `ListView`.

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    List<String> items;

    public ImageListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> items) {
        super(context, resource, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        Picasso.with(getContext())
               .load(items.get(position))
               .into((ImageView) convertView);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Read the [Picasso library documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/) if you want to add more options such as image placeholders, transformations, and more.

Finally, to use the adapter on your `ListView`, add this to your activity's `onCreate` method:

```
List<String> images = new ArrayList<String>();
images.add("http://hometowncolumbia.files.wordpress.com/2007/12/lol-cats-dont-look-behind-cat.jpg");
images.add("http://i232.photobucket.com/albums/ee245/topswing/cat-lol.jpg");

listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
listView.setAdapter(new ImageListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, images))
```

In a real application though, you'd probably want to load the image list from your server. You'd need to use an `AsyncTask` for that.

Comment: I just need to display a lot of images. This just looks hard to understand. I am really new with this android development thing, and this kind of things just make me confuse. I got a bunch of images in a folder in drawable and i want to display them with a ListView. Unless there's a different and better way to display them.

Answer (score 0):

Don't make things difficult, the solution is simple in the classic 3 steps

Step 1:
Make a `RelativeLayout` in XML. Move the image to desired position (always to center, but you can choose if left or right) and change `layout_height` to `wrap_content`

Step 2:
Create a custom adapter for ListView, if you do this, you'll be able to all any layout as an item

```
public class ImagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Activity mContext;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> mImages;

    public ImagesAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> listOfValues, ArrayList<Bitmap> images) {
        //The listOfValues is used when you make item click to get value
        //Each image must to have a text value
        super(context, R.layout.yourlayout, listOfValues);
        mContext = context;
        mImages = images;
    }

    @Override
    public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = mContext.getLayoutInflater();
        View returnView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) returnView.findViewById(R.id.yourimageid);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mImages.get(position));
        return returnView;
    }

}
```

Step 3:
Implement in your code

```
ImagesAdapter adapter = new ImagesAdapter(this, myList, myImages);
mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //volov = Values Of ListOfValues
        String volov = (String) myListView.getItemPosition(position);
        Log.i(TAG, "listOfValues is useful " + volov);
    }

});
```

Comment: How can it have "void" method type and "View" return type?